# How to toggle update model bool attribute?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

How to toggle `active` bool attribute in update action? I'm used to Rails, what is good practice in Phoenix?

Example code:

```
defmodule Todo.task do
  use Todo.Web, :model

  schema "task" do
    field :active, :boolean, default: false

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(active)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
end

defmodule Todo.TaskController do
  use Todo.Web, :controller
  alias Todo.Task

  def update(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    task = Repo.get_by(Task, id: id)
    # task.active = !task.active
    # task.save
    render(conn, "show.json", task: task)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [Ecto.Changeset](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html) with your new active state and then call [Repo.update/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:update/2).

```
  def update(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    task = Repo.get_by(Task, id: id)
    changeset = Task.changeset(task,%{active: !task.active})
    case Repo.update(changeset) do
      {:ok, task}         -> redirect(conn, to: task_path(conn, :show, task))
      {:error, changeset} -> render(conn, "edit.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

The pattern match when calling `Repo.update` or `Repo.insert` is the considered best practice for what you want to do.

Often you will call update with the params that you have pattern matched in the function:

```
  def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "task" => task_params}) do
    changeset = Task.changeset(task, task_params)
    case ...
  end
```

The `changeset/2` function defined on your model will ensure that only the fields specified can be modified. If these differ from the fields when updating, consider making an `update_changeset/2` function. There is nothing special about this function, you can define and use as many functions as you like that return a changeset.

Comment: So if I have many attributes in model then I can pass only one changed to changeset, that was the key. Can I create a model method and from it update only `active` flag and deal with changeset?

Comment: @luzny You specify the valid parameters (both optional and required) when you call `Ecto.Changeset.cast/4` in your `changeset` function. In this case you are specifying that `active` is required.

Comment: You can pass a model to `Repo.update/2` however I wouldn't recommend using it as it is being deprecated in 1.1 https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v110